# Превышено максимальное число кадров стека, поддерживаемое Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net-core, stackoverflow

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
При работе программы .net Core 3.1 (консольное приложение), периодически появляется ошибка (период появления ошибки всегда разный, может и через 1 минуту, так и через 20)
"System.Net.Security.dll!System.Net.SSPISecureChannelType.DecryptMessage Превышено максимальное число кадров стека, поддерживаемое Visual Studio."
Не указывается конкретный участок кода.
В какую сторону копать? что искать?

P.S. Это приложение выполняет роль обработчика данных. Данные поступают с сокета стороннего сервера.

[image: Exception]

Comment: Похоже что при каком-то условии у вас возникает бесконечная рекурсия. Надо наладить логгирование в критичных местах кода, хотя бы с помощью `Trace.WriteLine()` см. [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace?view=netcore-3.0).

Comment: @Bulson спасибо за наводку. Но дело не в бесконечном цикле. ПО получает из сети около 1 тыс. блоков данных в секунду (возможно они и называются кадрами)). Если обрабатывать каждый 10-ый кадр, то такой ошибки не происходит.  Исходя из вышесказанного есть предположение что где то в ограниченном "стеке" скапливаются еще не обработанные кадры и собственно переполняют данный стек. Для обработки кадров используется метод async await и Task. Информации по расширении данного стека найти не удалось. Как вариант, думаю попробовать запустить ПО на более мощном ПК.

Comment: @НикитаСтепанов, фрейм, в данном случае -- это кадр стека потока (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80), а не что-то пришедшее по сети, это раз. Предыдущий комментатор сказал Вам не о бесконечном цикле, а о бесконечной рекурсии, то есть, о ситуации, когда функция бесконечно вызывает сама себя. При вызове функции в стек помещаются ее параметры, в какой-то момент их там становится слишком много. И, собственно, глядя на скрин, я готов руку на отсечение дать, что дело именно в бесконечной рекурсии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему удалось решить только при помощи замены библиотеки для работы с прослушкой сокета.
Использовал "WebSocketSharp", поменял на "System.Net.WebSockets" и "Websocket.Client".
С новыми библиотеками таких ошибок больше не происходило.